# Custom validation via child control

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

So I'm working inside a directive that contains it's own form element and buttons, however all the controls must be transcluded through. The model for this particular view contains a property for total capacity, and a property that is a collection of compartments (separate entity). Each compartment has it's own capacity. I already have a function that will show an error on the view if/when the Total Capacity is not equal to the combined capacity of all compartments. The problem here is, since all my controls are transcluded through (and I'm not supposed to modify the parent directive) I have no clue if/how I can use that same function to mark the form as invalid to disable the save button. I was wondering if there is a solution (hopefully one that doesn't involve custom directives or services) that would allow me to set the parent form invalid if an expression returns true.

** UPDATE **

Sorry guys, I think I explained it backwards the first time. So this would be a good representation of what is going on in the html. (Also I haven't used stackoverflow much before this so bear with me)

edit-page-directive:

```
<div>
<form name="editForm">
<ng-transclude>

</ng-transclude>
<a class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
<a class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
</form>
</div>
```

View for this particular edit:

```
<edit-page>
    <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab>
            <!--Total Capacity input-->
            <input type="text" numeric="{min:1, format:'#,###.#'}" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}" class="form-control" id="tcCapacity" name="tcCapacity" data-ng-required="true" ng-model="vm.dataContext.entity.TotalCapacity" />
            <!--End Total Capacity-->
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab>
            <table>
                <tr><thead><th>...</th><th>Capacity</th><th>(Buttons for compartment add/remove)</th></thead></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="compartment in vm.dataContext.entity.TrailerConfigCompartments">
                    <td width="200">{{compartment.Sequence}}</td>
                    <!--Important input under this-->
                    <td><input type="text" numeric="{min:0, format:'#,###.#'}" class="form-control" ng-model="compartment.Capacity" data-ng-required="true" /></td>
                    <!--Important input above-->
                    <td align="right" style="padding-right:30px;">
                        <a class="btn" style="padding: .7em; color: black;" ng-click="vm.addCompartment(compartment.Sequence + 1)">
                            <span uib-tooltip="New compartment at sequence {{compartment.Sequence + 1}}" class="btn-edit" style='margin-left:5px'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="margin-top:3px"></span></span>
                        </a>
 &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <a class="btn" style="padding: .7em; color: black;" ng-click="vm.removeCompartment(compartment)">
                            <span uib-tooltip="Remove compartment" class="btn-edit" style='margin-left:5px'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="margin-top:3px"></span></span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
</edit-page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have something like

HTML

```
 <div data-ng-controller="FormController as vm">
    <form class="foo form">

       <input type="text"> // some inputs
       <input type="text"> // some inputs

       <transcluded-directive>

             <button class="foo button-to-disable">Do something</button> // button that should be disabled

       </transcluded-directive>


    </form>
 </div>
```

JS

```
.controller("FormController", function($scope) {

   var vm = this;

   vm.validateTotalCapacity = function () {
      // validation stuff
   }

});
```

So I think you can do something like:

HTML

```
 <div data-ng-controller="FormController as vm">
    <form class="foo form  {{vm.validateTotalCapacity() ? '' : 'form-has-errors'}}" >

       <input type="text"> // some inputs
       <input type="text"> // some inputs

       <transcluded-directive>

             <button class="foo button-to-disable">Do something</button> // button that should be disabled

       </transcluded-directive>


    </form>
 </div>
```

Look I put your form validator in `<form class="foo form">` and make condition for error class

CSS

```
  .form-has-errors .button-to-disable {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
       opacity: 0.5 
       // or your custom disabled styles
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I see, but I believe you could try this:

HTML

```
    <div>
        <form name="editForm"  class="{{editForm.$valid ? '' : 'form-has-errors '}}">
            <ng-transclude>

            </ng-transclude>
            <a class="btn btn-success">Save</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey thank you for responding so quickly, looks like I explained it backwards. I updated the question though to give you a good idea of what I'm working with

Answer (score 0):

So I realized I had misinterpreted the customValidation piece of angularjs. I thought any directive I'd have to create for validation would have to be added to the form element itself. Just as well I thought it would be alot harder to set up than it actually is.

For future reference:

1.) Create a directive and restrict it to an attribute

2.) Require ngModel for this directive

3.) Set up your link function:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {....}
```

4.) Add a function to the $validators object of the control you want to validate. Do this INSIDE of your link function. Ex:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    ngModel.$validators.validationFn = function(value) {
        //Where value is the current value of the control

        //In my case, where I want to compare value to the combined value of other
        //compartments I would send in whatever data I wanted via the scope property of 
        //this directive and compare the two in this function 
    }
}
```

5.) Return true if control is valid and vice versa

And that's it.

If you want to access this validator to display an error message just:

```
ng-show="vm.arbitraryInput.$error.validationFn"
```

Keep in mind that now if it returns true, then the input is invalid.